# How to get media url from JW Player?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, jwplayer

I need to know how i can access the direct media url from a file played in the JW Player by doing this with a chrome extension. That means I've got a website playing a video and I want to get the url of the video and use it in my script inside the extension.

Comment: What add on are you trying to use?

Comment: did you got the answer? please share

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can't easily access the innards of the Flash object, but</s> you can watch network connections made by the tab.

You can use `chrome.webRequest` to watch for requests filtered by URL patterns and tab ID. If the videos are served from a small collection of domains/paths, that should be enough to intercept the URL.

Comment: the version of jw player i'm looking at is html5 based